Is there a countable non-discrete linear order which satisfies the first-order theory of discrete linear orders?
A linear order $(L;\leq)$ is said to be a discrete linear order if for any two elements $x$ and $y$ of $L$, the interval $[x,y]$ contains only finitely many members. Now, that is not a first-order condition, and so the class $K$ of discrete linear orders is not first-order axiomatizable, at least I think it is not. However, $K$ does have an associated first-order theory $Th(K)$. Can someone exhibit a countable linear order which is not discrete, but which satisfies $Th(K)$?

That is not the standard definition of a discrete linear order.The usual definition in terms of successors and predecessors is a first-order property.

Yes. By compactness and downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorems, there exists a countable linear order $(L, \leq)$ containing $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ as an elementary submodel but has an infinite element $\infty$, i.e., $\infty > n$ for all natural numbers $\infty$. In particular, $[0, \infty]$ is not finite.

IIRC, $\mathbb{N}$ adjoining a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the end is ee to $\mathbb{N}$, so that’s a concrete example. I’d rather not run through the argument showing that though, so I just chose a “cheating” way in my answer.

As long as the discrete linear order $L$ is infinite, you should have no issues constructing an elementary extension of $L$ with an "infinite gap" between two elements. In particular, you can show by compactness that the set of formulas $\phi(x, y)$ asserting that there are at least $n$ different elements between $x$ and $y$ for all $n$ is satisfiable, and so a 2-type that can be realized in an elementary extension of $L$.
